# Is it valid to allocate memory to a structure's pointer without knowing the size of its sub-structures?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memory-management

Consider the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct word {
    char* data;
};

struct sentence {
    struct word* data;
    int word_count;
};

struct paragraph {
    struct sentence* data  ;
    int sentence_count;
};

struct document {
    struct paragraph* data;
    int paragraph_count;
};

void main()
{
    int total_paragraph = 5;   //I'm myself assigning total number of paragraphs for simplicity
    
    struct document doc;
    
    doc.data = malloc(total_paragraph*(sizeof(struct paragraph)));  //Statement which I have a doubt!!!

    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

Firstly, logically, Is the statement(malloc one, in which I have a doubt) valid?

If yes, how does the computer assigns 5 units of memory (each unit is of struct paragraph size) without knowing the size of `struct paragraph` (as we haven't malloced its content, the pointer `data` pointing to a struct sentence type)?

Comment: The  `malloc()` statement is valid.  The compiler knows the size of `struct paragraph` — you've told it what it consists of.  Using `malloc()` doesn't make the size known; the declarations (definitions) make the size known.  You can allocate pointers to structures without knowing the details of what's in the structure — that makes it an opaque type.  But you can't access the contents of the structure, or allocate copies of the structure, without knowing its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to allocate structures without its substructures being defined. After all, you can't know the size of a structure without knowing the size of its substructures.

However, `struct paragraph` doesn't contain any substructures. It contains a structure pointer, an `int`, and possibly padding. The size of all those things *are* known.

The code you posted is perfectly fine.

Comment: Just for clarity, please answer this question: **assume 'sizeof(int) = 4 bytes' and 'sizeof(pointer) = 4 bytes'. then sizeof(struct document) = 8 bytes, is it true?**

Comment: @Algorithmophile, That is not correct. There could be padding. It's very unlikely with those sizes, though. (Note that not all pointers are necessarily the same size, as far as history and the C standard is concerned. But all struct pointers would have to be the same size.)

Comment: @Algorithmophile, It's not the one I was looking for, but here's a [decent explanation of padding](https://dev.to/pallavi121/structure-padding-in-c-data-structures-3jjj)  That said, it doesn't mention that padding can happen at the end (so that each struct in an array of structs is aligned).

Comment: [This goes in more detail](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/). But it doesn't explain why alignment speeds things up like the first link does.

Answer (score 2):

> without knowing the size of struct paragraph (as we haven't malloced its content, the pointer data pointing to a struct sentence type)?
> c
> pointers
> struct

Why do we need to `malloc` a structure to know it's size? What is the size of  this structure?

```
struct document {
    struct paragraph* data;
    int paragraph_count;
};
```

It has a pointer and an integer. A pointer has a fixed size(usually 64-bit on 64-bit machines and 32-bit on 32-bit machines) and and integer has a fixed size(usually 32 bit). so, the size of the struct in bytes is `sizeof(any_pointer)` + `sizeof(int)` + padding. All of those three are known to the compiler.

Comment: what is **padding**?

Comment: Ok. I got some information about padding, here's the link:  https://www.javatpoint.com/structure-padding-in-c  **thanks for help** .

Comment: @Algorithmophile Padding is well, padding between the members of a struct. It's for optimisations as a CPU can read 4 bytes at a time(if 32 bit instructions are supported) and not 1 byte at a time. It can cause some issues. In this case there should be 4 bytes padding.